# Using loops to return in a method

Tags: java, loops, methods

So, I need to `return` either a position in an `array` or a -1 if the goal number is not found. The problem is when I use `return` inside an `if` `else` statement, I get an error because the program will not go into the `if` loop. Here is my current code:

```
public int search(int num1)
{
for(int i=0;i<scores.length;i++)
    {
        if(scores[i]==num1)
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }

    }
}
```

This keeps giving me an error saying no return statement. Is there a way to do this logic without the error?
thanks guys

Comment: Remove the `else` block.  Put `return -1;` after the end of the `for` block.

Comment: think about what your code does. It checks element 0, and no matter what, returns immediately. That's probably not what you want. The compiler is looking at your code and going "well, if `scores.length` is zero, the for loop is bypassed. So... where's the return statement after the for loop?"

Comment: FYI, the reason for the error is that if `scores.length` is 0, the loop will never execute and the method would never return.  (Actually, it appears that the Java compiler assumes that _any_ `for` loop with a termination condition could be executed zero times.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `for` loop is not entered, then there is no `return` statement.  This could happen if `scores.length` is `0`.  You must supply a `return` statement in all cases of execution, or the compiler will catch a case without a `return` statement and give a compiler error.

Move the `return -1` after the `for` loop, so that you only return `-1` if you went through the entire loop and didn't find `num1`.  That also means that the `else` block is unnecessary -- remove it.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you so much @rgettman I knew it was something simple to get it to ignore my for loop if needed. Totally solved it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it gives you error because it might think that the loop might not be executed. in order for it to run it has to be a return statement outside a loop or an if statement.

here is an adjustment i did with your code.

```
    public int search(int num1) {
        int x = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            if(scores[i]==num1) {
                x = i;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
```